# Erro ao importar banco Postgre

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, importação

Tenho um banco pra importar, ele é nativo do *PostgreSQL* e está com extensão `.sql`, estou tentando importar no `PgAdmin4` mas não consigo de forma alguma.
Ai está uma imagem do erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "por favor utilize o psql"

Answer (score 3):

A restauração usando `pg_restore`, que é o que está sendo usado pelo PGAdmin não suporta arquivos sql, pois é necessário ter arquivos de formato de backup gerados.

Para usar o arquivo sql, você pode abrir o console do pgadmin e escolher no menu a opção Abrir > Arquivo, selecionar o sql e depois acionar a ação Executar.

A melhor opção, porém, é usar o psql (linha de comando). De preferência no mesmo diretório do arquivo, para evitar ter que escrever o caminho do arquivo:

```
psql -h nomeservidor -U nomeusuario -d nomebancodedados < /caminho/nomearquivo.sql
```

ou

```
psql -h nomeservidor -U nomeusuario -d nomebancodedados < nomearquivo.sql
```

Para ter mais garantia, você pode se conectar ao servidor e chamar o arquivo depois de conectado:

1) Conectar: `psql -h nomeservidor -U nomeusuario -d nomebancodedados`

2) Executando o arquivo: `\i nomedoarquivo`

Comment: Quando eu uso esse comando não acontece nada, ele volta pra eu entrar com comandos novamente.

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema com o seguinte comando: \i caminhoDoArquivo, ele importou todas as tabelas pra mim.

Comment: Isso. É uma outra opção. Eu editei a solução para incluir esta. Provavelmente você não conseguiu nas iniciais em razão do caminho do arquivo no formato Windows ser diferente do que o que eu indiquei.

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa: Qual o caminho que eu coloco o arquivo pra que eu não precise colocar o caminho dele? Eu uso windows10

Comment: Você só não precisa colocar o caminho dele se executar o `psql` no mesmo diretório em que o arquivo está.